# Generating images with non-repeating random patterns

Tags: svg, random, language-agnostic

I've been trying to create a special random pattern for some time. For example random black dots, like this:

https://picload.org/thumbnail/riogwpll/pattern2.jpg

However, I need a much larger image with about 100,000 points / circles. In principle, no problem, however, the SVG with several MB then becomes too large to open it, for example, with Inkscape, because each circle is drawn individually. Any ideas how this could be realize better resulting in a smaller file. I have already tried something with pattern. Problem is that it should be a truly random, non-repeating pattern.

It's not necessary to do this with dots it could also look like this:
[enter image description here][1]
https://picload.org/thumbnail/riogwwdr/pattern1.jpg

For ideas / suggestions, I am grateful.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Please show your coding attempts. The code should not be in the MBs, or is it?

Comment: Take a look at the SVG filter primitive for [Perlin turbulence](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feTurbulenceElement). From a glance, your examples can visually be achieved with it. Whether its appropriate might be a question of mathematical analysis.

Comment: Look at David Dailey's page on turbulence to understand how these work: http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/SVGOpen2010/filters2.htm

Answer (score 5):

Is it something like this that you are after?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="600">
  <defs>
    <filter id="dots" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feTurbulence baseFrequency=".1" numOctaves="1" seed="42" />
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
      <feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="2" />
       <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" style="fill:#888; stroke:#bbd; stroke-width:2px; filter: url(#dots)" />
</svg>
```

How this works:

1. `<feTurbulence baseFrequency=".1" numOctaves="1" seed="42" />` generates some random noise. Remove the `seed` attribute if you want a different pattern each time.
2. `<feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>` converts the noise to greyscale.
3. `<feGaussianBlur result="blur" stdDeviation="2" />` blurs the noisey pattern so that the dots merge together a little.  Experiment with this value to vary the "blobbiness".
4. `<feComponentTransfer>` thresholds the grey values to either black or white.

Comment: Be careful with Perlin noise, since it is generally implemented in a way that it repeats itself after 512 units. Depending of the feature and image size, the technique you presented can generate repeating pattern.